# Testbench using Task operation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, testbench

I have to write a testbench using "tasks" to verify the functionality of an 8-bit ALU. My tasks are not getting simulated properly in EDA playground. Can anyone please tell me where my mistake is?  In syntax or in logic?

## Design of 8-bit ALU

```
module alu(input [7:0] a,b,
                 input [3:0] alu_select,
                 output reg [7:0] alu_out
                );
  
  always @(*)
    begin
      case(alu_select)
        
        4'b0000 : begin alu_out = a + b; $display("Addition operation"); end
        4'b0001 : begin alu_out = a - b; $display("Subtraction operation"); end 
        4'b0010 : begin alu_out = a * b; $display("Multiplication operation"); end
        4'b0011 : begin alu_out = a / b; $display("Division operation"); end
        4'b0100 : begin alu_out = a % b; $display("Modulo operation"); end
        4'b0101 : begin alu_out = a & b; $display("Bitwise-AND operation"); end
        4'b0110 : begin alu_out = a | b; $display("Bitwise-OR operation"); end
        4'b0111 : begin alu_out = a && b; $display("Logical-AND operation"); end
        4'b1000 : begin alu_out = a || b; $display("Logical-OR operation"); end
        4'b1001 : begin alu_out = a ^ b; $display("XOR operation"); end
        4'b1010 : begin alu_out = ~ a ; $display("Bitwise-Invert operation"); end
        4'b1011 : begin alu_out = a >> b; $display("Right Shift operation"); end
        4'b1100 : begin alu_out = a << b; $display("Left Shift operation"); end
        4'b1101 : begin alu_out = a + 1; $display("Increment operation"); end
        4'b1110 : begin alu_out = a - 1; $display("Decrement operation"); end
        4'b1111 : begin alu_out = ! a; $display("Logical-Invert operation"); end
        default : alu_out = 8'bXXXXXXXX;
      endcase
    end
  
endmodule
```

## Testbench

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

task addition;
  input [7:0] a,b;
  output reg [7:0] c;
  begin 
    c = a + b;
  end
endtask

module alu_tb_task;
  
  reg [7:0] a,b;
  logic [7:0] alu_out;
  reg [3:0] alu_select;

  alu uut(
    .a(a), .b(b), .alu_out(alu_out), .alu_select(alu_select)
  );
  

initial begin
      
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1,alu_tb_task);
    
    a=8'h01;
    b=8'h02;
    alu_select=4'b0000;
    addition(a,b,alu_out);

 end
    
endmodule
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to this site. This is a bit unclear: what does "not getting simulated properly" mean, specifically?

Comment: You can also include the link of the EDA Playground in your question.

Comment: It is good if you include the error messages you get, or waveforms. Also mention the simulator used.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.

The first is you are driving `all_out` from an output of your module *and* making a procedural assignment for the task call. That is illegal. What you want to do is create a separate variable and then compare the result from your module and testbench.

The second problem is you are not giving any time for the results to propagate and be observed. You need at least a unit delay.

So modify your testbench like:

```
  logic [7:0] alu_out_actual, alu_out_expected;

 alu uut(
    .a(a), .b(b), .alu_out(alu_out_actual), .alu_select(alu_select)
  );
...
initial begin
   ... 
   addition(a,b,alu_out_expected);
   #1ns;
   if (alu_out_actual != alu_out_expected) $error("mismatch");
```

A few other comments:

- in SystemVerilog, even though they are synonymous, prefer using `logic` over `reg` keywords. Avoids confusion with ***reg**ister*.
- It's poor programing practice to declare things outside of a module. It creates problems as your code gets larger. Move your task declaration inside your module, or declare it inside a package to be imported.
- You should not be using a `task` for a routine that does not consume time. Use a `function` with a `void` return type, or make `c` the return value.

Answer (score 0):

The `task` must be declared inside the body of the `module`:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module alu_tb_task;

task addition;
  input [7:0] a,b;
  output reg [7:0] c;
  begin 
    c = a + b;
  end
endtask
  
  reg [7:0] a,b;
  logic [7:0] alu_out;
  reg [3:0] alu_select;

// etc.
```

Also, you should not drive the same signal in the testbench from both the `uut` and the task.  You should create a new signal in the testbench:

```
logic [7:0] alu_out_tb;

//...

addition(a,b,alu_out_tb);
```

You must decide what you will do with the new signal.